# Using checkbox selection and row selection together in PrimeNg table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNg table component and needs to implement row selection. I have the following code:

```
    <p-table
        [value]="data"
        [columns]="columns"
        [(selection)]="selectedItems"
        selectionMode="multiple">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <p-tableHeaderCheckbox style="margin-left: 5px;"></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
            </th>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="row">
            <td>
                <p-tableCheckbox [value]="row"></p-tableCheckbox>
            </td>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Basically, I am using the Checkbox selection and multiple selection without metakey as given in the documentation [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/selection). Now when I click on the row, it is selecting and the checkbox is also checked. But when I click on the checkbox, it is not getting selected. If I click on the `Select All`, then also it is selecting all the rows. When I checked using Developer Tools, it is not making the `aria-checked` to true even though the click is detected.

Any workaround for fixing this issue?

Comment: Try adding the `dataKey` attribute to the p-table. Assuming you have something in the actual data to key on.

Answer (score 14):

@Arun's answer is correct. I'm just adding some formatting if someone also stumbles on this problem and is short of time ;) :

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="data">
       <td>
          <p-tableCheckbox [pSelectableRow]="data" [value]="data"></p-tableCheckbox>
       </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

It also works well without providing [index] to the tableCheckbox.

Answer (score 9):

Yes R.Richards is right adding `dataKey` should resolve the problem. But still without dataKey just add this `<p-tableCheckbox [value]="row" [pSelectableRow]="row"></p-tableCheckbox>`with your row checkbox. This should work as I remember I had done something like this earlier with my code:)

Comment: pSelectableRow not a property of p-tableCheckBox

Answer (score 2):

I've observed that when you add `pSelectableRow` to both `tr` and `p-tableCheckbox`, like in the @Arun's answer, selection is triggered 3 times. First, it adds selection to selections array, second it removes it and finally in the 3rd time adds again.
So if you act on selection change it can be a problem. I cannot figure out the exact reason though, strange behaviour.

Also, please note that this particular use case is not [officially supported](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6045).

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the checkboxes behavior using simple css - `pointer-events: none`. Your click should still affect the row, but not propagate down to the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using p-tableCheckbox and pSelectableRow. Removing the selectionMode binding solved it. As in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-table-selection-checkbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example.